# Reusing JQuery Plugins /CSS in wordpress project

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've 3rd party JQuery plugins that I need to reuse across my wordpress plugins on a website project. Is it better practice to put these JQuery plugins inside a common folder (Say inside wp-content) instead of putting them inside a wordpress plugin and then referencing it ?

i.e. instead of

```
 wp_enqueue_scripts('script_id', plugins_url() . '/plugin-abc/bootstrap-tagsinput.js', array('jquery'), $plugin_version, 'all');
```

^^ The above apprroach also creates dependencies between plugins i.e. to install plugin-xyz which needs bootstrap-tagsinput.js, I need to have plugin-abc installed first or atleast in the plugins directory.

I can do instead reference a folder common-assets directly under wp-content

```
wp_enqueue_scripts('script_id', content_url() . '/common-assets/bootstrap-tagsinput.js', array('jquery'), $plugin_version, 'all');
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use the plugin directory, that way it will all be packed together.